# Parsing a string (gotten from rabbitmq) into JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am using rabbittmq to consume a JSON (that I got from mongoDB) in nodeJS application. Below mentioned is code snippet :

```
        ch.consume(q, function(msg){
        var clone = msg.content.toString();
        var cloned = JSON.parse(clone.replace(/_/g,""));
        //var cloned = JSON.parse(clone);
        console.log(' [x] Recieved %s', cloned); // shows correct JSON 
        var keys = Object.keys(cloned);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                 console.log('keys....', cloned[keys[i]]);
        } //-----Keys as coming as one character per key
```

If I try to parse "clone", I get unexpected error due to underscore at position 0. And not able to parse it to a JSON.

And then when I replace all underscore with a blank string, I am not able to parse it to a JSON as error comes stating "Unexpected token v in JSON at position 2".

In order to see if its parsed correctly I am displaying keys. The keys come as

```
keys.... {
keys....
keys.... v
keys.... :
keys....
keys.... 0
keys.... ,
keys....

keys....
keys....
keys.... f
keys.... o
keys.... l
keys.... i
```

Please help me here !! Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Perhaps you should show the sample content and what you expect as output

Comment: Sure. Sample content as output is :
{ v: 0,
  folioNum: 44,
  firstName: 'newname',
  lastName: 'newname',
  address: '123',
  checkinDate: '1st Aug',
  checkoutDate: '2nd Aug',
  ratePgm: 'rega',
  status: 'RS',
  notes: 'NA',
  id: 599a5dc585198131c4e4852d }

I see this upon doing console.log for cloned. I want to export this JSON and use it another nodeJS application. Hence, the need to parse it correctly.

Comment: `toString()`is ur problem, You are looping through the string..

Comment: Every keys must be quoted by " in JSON, but from your output it looks like it is an js object originally.

Comment: Thank you WangJie !! It got added after putting " around the keys !! Thanks for help!

Comment: Thanks to you Subburaj, I had to manipulate use of toString() as well.Got your point! Thanks.